# How to use ES6 module system in multiple file?

Tags: javascript, module

I want to use **the ES6 module system** in multiple files at once a time.
examples: I have one **entry point index.js** file where is my all code will be run
and I have also 2 another file like ***exampleOne.js and example.Two.js***. so I want to execute code from two other files into the entry point file which name is **index.js**. SO how can I do that
I have tried but didn't successful at all

Comment: What did you try? Are you targeting node or a browser? If targeting a browser, how are you bundling your code ?

Comment: I am binding my code with es6 class method

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to export the modules from the `exampleOne.js` and `exampleTwo.js` files, and then import them into `index.js`.  That'll look something like this:

*exampleOne.js*

```
export function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

*exampleTwo.js*

```
export function subtract(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

*index.js*

```
import {add} from './exampleOne';
import {subtract} from './exampleTwo';

console.log(add(2,3)); // 5
console.log(subtract(2,1)); // 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Sternjobname bro your code is working for me